# how to get cordinates of points drawn on ractangle perimeter using circular function?

Tags: math, 2d

I have rectangle with known base and height. I need coordinates of points on rectangle perimeter which is obtained by drawing lines from the center of base after every known degree (Say 1 degree) for the range of 0 -180 degree.

To get my question clearly i have attached image below. Kindly have a look.

[image: RectPeriCoordinates]

Comment: This looks like a math homework assignment.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes. Have mentioned that in attached image. I am using rotation matrix to get all coordinates of dot drawn on semi circle. and was thinking to translate it by x' and y' to obtain the p1', p2' etc. points on rectangle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1):

Clues for a possible approach:

1. Find x-coordinate of intersection of ray with angle `Theta` and top edge of rectangle (note special cases `Theta = 0, Theta = Pi`)
2. If this coordinate lies outside of rectangle, find y-coordinate of intersection of ray and vertical edge (choose right one depending on angle)